# How can i load data in individual product popup in magento

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I want to show product details in pop-up on click product name in product page. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
                    if (count($data['product']) > 0) {
                      foreach ($data['product'] as $product) { 
                      $product_id         =   $product->getId();
                      $product_name       =   $product->getName();
                      $isporductImage     =   $product->getImage();
                      $product_image      =   Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/product" . $product->getImage();
                      $isproductthumbnail = $product->getThumbnail();
                      $product_thumbnail  =   Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/product" . $product->getThumbnail();
                      $collectionimage    = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/category/thumb/" . $data['collection']['image'];
                      $productplaceholderImage = $this->getSkinUrl() . "whi/assets/images/whi_placeholder.png";

                    ?>
                  <div class="celeb-post" id="products-listing" style="text-align: center; width: 228px;">

                    <?php if ($isproductthumbnail != "") { ?>
                                  <div class="image-div" style="background: url('<?php echo $product_thumbnail;?>');">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $product_thumbnail; ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                  </div>

                          <?php }elseif ($isporductImage != "") { ?>
                                  <div class="image-div" style="background: url('<?php echo $product_image;?>');">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                  </div>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                    <div class="image-div" style="background: url('<?php echo $productplaceholderImage;?>');">     
                                      <img src="<?php echo $productplaceholderImage ?>" alt="celeb" />
                                    </div>

                            <?php } ?>
                        <div class="hover-image-bg" style="width: 86.9%; height: 69.3%;">
                                  <a href="#"><img style="padding-left: 38px;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/heart.png"></a>
                                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/bag.png"></a>
                                  <a href="#"> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/move.png"></a>
                                  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/assign.png"></a>
                        </div>

                    <div style="clear:both; height:10px;"></div>
                        <div class="celeb-name-title ucase clearfix" style="text-align:center;"><a href="#login-box5" class="login-window5"><?php echo $product_name; ?></a></div>

                </div>


                <?php
                    }
                  }else{ ?>
                  <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tr><td style="text-align: center; height: 100px; font-weight: bold;">No Product found in Collection, you can add by clicking on +New button at the top right.</td></tr>
                  </table>
                  <?php
                  }  
                ?>
```

And login-box5 code is:

```
<div id="login-box5" class="login-popup login-popup5">
<a href="#" class="close"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" style="width:100%;" /></a>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/new-collection.png">
<div class="brand-position-outfite" id="celeb-position-outfite">
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>whi/assets/images/celeb.png">
<h5>Brand Name</h5>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<h5>Product Name</h5>
<BR><BR>
<textarea rows="10" class="add-txtarea-cmt">Description....</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

So, simply if I click on Product Name, then popup will appear and show details of that product, like product name and product description. Can anyone help me to sort out this problem. I think this can be done through AJAX, JavaScript but don't know how can I embed script in my code. 
Waiting of your kind response thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show us what you get so far using this code mate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to create ajax function to load the data. Also you can create ajax request handle so that particular template will be used to show the data. You can get better idea about the functionality using the below Quick view extension:

https://github.com/czettnersandor/magento-quick-view-ajax

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you output your "popup"-information in your existing product-listing/view template in a special div-block which is connected to your product.

A simple example for product listing:

you list your productnames and popupdata in the template/catalog/product/list.phtml:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
  <h3 class="productpreview" data-sku="<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
  <div class="popup" id="pop_<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>">
    /*insert your other productdata here*/
    <?php echo $_product->getShortDescription(); ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

The class `popup` should be `display: none;` in css
I would suggest that you then use something like [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display that content. If you have access to jquery, you could also write this to show the content and with added css you could easily make a cool looking popup:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.productpreview').click(function(){
    var sku = $(this).data('sku');
    $('#pop_'+sku).toggle();
  });
});
```

if you want the functionality in the product view page you modifiy template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
  <h3 class="productpreview" data-sku="<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
  <div class="popup" id="pop_<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>">
    /*insert your other productdata here*/
    <?php echo $_product->getShortDescription(); ?>
  </div>
```

It is the same CSS/Jquery code, you only need to remove the foreach-loop.